# Positive word for Premonition

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, connotation

I wanted to use the word "Premonition" in a sentence, but when I checked the meaning I got "A feeling of evil to come", which was far from what I wanted to convey.

So I checked synonyms like "boding", "foreboding", "forewarning", "Presentiment", and so on. All had ominous connotations or a negativity or a sense of evil attached to the meaning.

So here I am, asking if there is a positive word for premonition, without negative implications.

---

UPDATE: "Hunch" is the word I select as matching my requirements, from all the answers I got.

Comment: Ian Dury calls positive premonitions **glimpses**, as he details in his wonderful song "[You'll See Glimpses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTvvERaHog8)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Divination**

1.
the practice of attempting to foretell future events or discover hidden knowledge by occult or supernatural means.

2.
augury; prophecy: The divination of the high priest was fulfilled.

3.
perception by intuition; instinctive foresight.

A more informal word could be **Hunch**

Comment: While I was far from using Divination , I like the informal word Hunch , which is exactly what I had , and it has no negativity.

Answer (score 3):

A simple "prediction" would probably work.  It more relates to a suspicion rather than a 'gut feeling', but it carries no negative connotations towards the suspicion.

"Premonition" itself doesn't carry too heavy a negative connotation either, so you'd probably be safe using it as-is.  Though I wouldn't use "boding", "foreboding" or "forewarning", since those carry a little more negative weight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did consider "prediction" , but I was not really predicting. Yes in the end, I did stick with Premonition.

Answer (score 3):

A ***vision*** would also achieve the same effect with no negative connotations.

Though a vision portrays a vivid premonition where the person receiving it is able to see things that will happen in future, and is far more descriptive than a gut-feeling or hunch.

If you intend to portray a gut-feeling, vision will not fit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though vision does fit with positive meaning, I was not really having a vivid vision. I ended up using Premonition itself.

Answer (score 1):

Precognition. Carries a serious psychiatric stain in German though. Alike all precognitive people are automatically suffering schizophrenia or worse.

I would summarize "clear-minded estimation", but I don't know how to bring that down to one word. INTUITION could be used for it though.

Paradoxically (?) there are more "clear-minded estimations" by scientists than by fortune-tellers and esoteric-fans.

Comment: Even though my question is 18 months old, I like this answer !!  PS: Welcome to ELU !!

Comment: Thank you for your benevolence. I was amused how many of my other critics forgot to apply the same standards & rules to other participants. My best wishes for you, and remember that I might need a while to score the reputation for spontaneous comments. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just say "positive premonition". It's thought provoking and challenges the reader's definition of premosition.  There are adjectives for a reason.

Comment: +1 , It is a simple but valid alternative !! PS : Welcome to ELU !!